# Reshape / merge columns in Pandas dataframe after using pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, dataframe

The following pivot function is working but I need to reformat results. Essentially removing the 'financialyear' label, and moving 'business' up to the same line as the financial years.

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='business', columns='financialyear', values='amount', aggfunc=np.sum)
```

current output:

```
financialyear                 2013          2014
business
Division A                      34            23
Division B                      32            61
Division C                     134             3
```

desired output:

```
business                      2013          2014
Division A                      34            23
Division B                      32            61
Division C                     134             3
```

Comment: 'financialname' is the name of the column index, so you can do `df.columns.name = None` to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be:

```
df.columns.name='business' #will change financialyear to business
```

Then remove the blank row:

```
df.index.name=None
```